# Error in javascript generated by Typescript enum

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

I've defined the following enum in Typescript:

```
enum ColorType {
    None = 0,
    Default = 1,
    RGB = 2,
    ColorSet = 3,
    Custom = 4
}
```

This compiles down to the following javascript:

```
(function (ColorType) {
    ColorType[ColorType["None"] = 0] = "None";
    ColorType[ColorType["Default"] = 1] = "Default";
    ColorType[ColorType["RGB"] = 2] = "RGB";
    ColorType[ColorType["ColorSet"] = 3] = "ColorSet";
    ColorType[ColorType["Custom"] = 4] = "Custom";
})(ColorType || (ColorType = {}));
```

This looks correct and similar to the [Tristate enum in the documentation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html#enums-are-open-ended). However when I run the code in the browser, both Firefox and Chrome complain about `ColorType` being not defined on the last line of the enum definition (i.e. `(ColorType || (ColorType = {}))`). I think it's specifically the first one. When I manually edit the code to:

```
(function (ColorType) {
    ColorType[ColorType["None"] = 0] = "None";
    ColorType[ColorType["Default"] = 1] = "Default";
    ColorType[ColorType["RGB"] = 2] = "RGB";
    ColorType[ColorType["ColorSet"] = 3] = "ColorSet";
    ColorType[ColorType["Custom"] = 4] = "Custom";
})(ColorType = {});
```

it works fine in both Firefox and Chrome.

I don't understand why the code generated by Typescript generates the error, it looks like they are trying to either pass in an already existing `ColorType` variable or create an empty object if it doesn't exist. But if it's wrong, is this an error in the Typescript compiler?  I'm using TSC 1.7.40.24720.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're just cutting and pasting *part* of the output?

The compiler generates this code for an enum:

```
var ColorType; // <---- this is the line you're missing
(function (ColorType) {
    ColorType[ColorType["None"] = 0] = "None";
    ColorType[ColorType["Default"] = 1] = "Default";
    ColorType[ColorType["RGB"] = 2] = "RGB";
    ColorType[ColorType["ColorSet"] = 3] = "ColorSet";
    ColorType[ColorType["Custom"] = 4] = "Custom";
})(ColorType || (ColorType = {}));
```

If you skip the `var`, you're going to get errors like you describe.

Comment: Yes, this is only a small part of the outputted file. Guess what, the line above contains: `//# sourceMappingURL=somefilename.js.mapvar ColorType;`, The build script concatenates a couple of files into one output file and the `var ColorType` ends up at the end of the comment of the previous file due to a lack of a carriage return. So, easy fix, thanks!